# Python set output file is empty

Tags: python, shell

I am writing a Python script to read in a file, read through that file line by line and parse out data from that file to another text file via user command line argument. Right now, I am able to read the input file line by line and parse out the data via command line argument. However, the output file that I am trying to write to is empty(it does not content the data I want to parse out).

temp.log contain:

```
06 May 19 03:40:35 3 abCodeClearTrap Error Clear Trap (agent: 12367a12, 
chassis:12367a12, ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT, csssi: EXTIFG, clearedID: 
0x089088394)
06 May 19 03:44:35 3 abCodeErrorTrap Error Trap (agent: 12368a15, chassis: 
12368a15, ErrIdText: Skip this item, csssi: SSRSSR, clearedID: 
0x089088394)
```

My code so far:

```
import re, sys

with open('temp.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

output_file = open ('output.txt', 'w')

data = []
for line in lines:
   date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group()    
   time = line.split()[3]
   ids = line.split()[4]
   row = [date, time, ids]

   if 'agent' in sys.argv:
       try:
          agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
          row.append(agent)
      except:
          agent = 'agent:'
  if 'err' in sys.argv:
      try:
          errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
          row.append(errID)
      except:
          errID = 'ErrIdText:'
  if 'clear' in sys.argv:
      try:
          clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
          row.append(clear)
      except:
          clear = 'clearedID:'

  data.append(row)
  output_file.writelines(row)

  for row in data:
  print(row)

  output_file.close()
```

I am expecting to write the output to a file call "output.txt" but that file is not generated by the code.

So the user will run the command line argument 
    python export.py date agent 
And I expect the output.txt file will have the list of date and agent but it is empty

Comment: Why would you expect that file to be created? You've done nothing at all that would create such a file or write to it.

Comment: After `output_file = row`, I'm surprised you don't get an `AttributeError` on `output_file.writelines()`. (Assuming `output_file` was ever an opened file in the first place.)

Comment: I do have the AttributeError. Is there a way for me to create the file and write to it?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing writing to file. Try to add something similar to this instead of your last three lines:

```
with open('output.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines(row)
```

Comment: @petelam hmm...I am not sure but there might be an issue due to these lines: ` for row in data: print(row)`. I think that `row` variable might be overwritten. Also, could you tell me if the file was created?

Comment: the file is created but it's empty

Comment: Could you share with us what does `for row in data: print(row)` prints? Also as mentioned above you should change this loop. For example `for row_ in data: print(row_)`. Moreover, if you have an error with encoding you can try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You did it right at the beginning, but failed to do it again in the end.
When you want to access a file, you have to `open` it first, and you did not do that in the end.

So, you should change your last 3 lines to something resembling

```
f = open(filename, mode) # mode probably "w" or "a"
f.writelines(pieces_of_data)
f.close()
```

Comment: So i have mine as follow 
    output_file = open ('output.txt', 'w')
    output_file.writelines(row)
    output_file.close()

however, output.txt is still empty

Comment: Not in the code you presented. Or are you talking about some improvements you did to your previous code? If that's the case, you should check if "row" isn't empty.